# SPIP installation doesnt recognize sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, installation, spip

SPIP 4.2.8 expects php sqlite function, and does not recognize sqlite3 function.
Consequently the SQlite radio button is not proposed in the installation process
(screen 1 of 4)

spip_loader.php
The installation page should propose sqlite as database to be used
Nothing is proposed.